equivalence of statements
Let's consider the following statements:
(a) $f(x_1, y_1, z_1)\neq f(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ for $x_1 \neq x_2$, $y_1 \neq y_2$ and $z_1 \neq z_2$.
(b) $f(x, y_1, z_1)\neq f(x, y_2, z_2)$ for  $y_1 \neq y_2$ and $z_1 \neq z_2$.
(c) $f(x_1, y, z_1)\neq f(x_2, y, z_2)$ for $x_1 \neq x_2$  and $z_1 \neq z_2$.
(d) $f(x_1, y_1, z)\neq f(x_2, y_2, z)$ for $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $y_1 \neq y_2$.
I am confused about the relationship between these statements. Does (a) imply (b), (c) or (d) since (a) is most general? Or does none of them imply the others and all of these statements need to be stated as above?

Are you asking what does (a) imply?

Yes, I'm wondering if (a) is stated, then (b), (c) and (d) are redundant and these can be removed.

None of the remaining statements follow from (a).
To see that (a) does not imply (b), consider the function:
$$f(x,y,z)= x$$
(a) is satisfied, but (b) is not.
To see that (a) does not imply (c), write $f(x,y,z)=y$. A similar counter example exists for the last question.
